# Can I check response when the request is redirected?

Tags: http, go

We can register [CheckRedirect](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) to check the next request when the request is redirected. Is there a way that I can get the response for the first request when it's redirected?

Answer (score 2):

The way it is currently implemented, it doesn't seem possible to have a look at the response by default (unless you implement yourself what `Do()` does).
See [`src/net/http/client.go#L384-L399`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/debe12cfcf9e0672bce0972cc22ff093f215ac59/src/net/http/client.go#L384-L399):

```
if shouldRedirect(resp.StatusCode) {
        // Read the body if small so underlying TCP connection will be re-used.
        // No need to check for errors: if it fails, Transport won't reuse it anyway.
        const maxBodySlurpSize = 2 << 10
        if resp.ContentLength == -1 || resp.ContentLength <= maxBodySlurpSize {
            io.CopyN(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body, maxBodySlurpSize)
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
        if urlStr = resp.Header.Get("Location"); urlStr == "" {
            err = fmt.Errorf("%d response missing Location header", resp.StatusCode)
            break
        }
        base = req.URL
        via = append(via, req)
        continue
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the first response? It will be pretty boring.

I think the most sensible thing would be to disable automatically following redirects (always return a non-nil error from `CheckRedirect`) and handle the redirection yourself in which case you have full access to all requests/responses.

Comment: To set cookies and check the redirect status number

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this:

Any http request / response could be patched within a custom `RoundTripper`, including redirects:

```golang
type RedirectChecker struct{}

func (RedirectChecker) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // e.g. patch the request before send it
    req.Header.Set("user-agent", "curl/7.64.1")

    resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)

    if err == nil && resp != nil {
        switch resp.StatusCode {
        case
            http.StatusMovedPermanently,
            http.StatusFound,
            http.StatusTemporaryRedirect,
            http.StatusPermanentRedirect:

            // e.g. stop further redirections
            // roughly equivalent to http.ErrUseLastResponse
            resp.StatusCode = http.StatusOK

            // e.g. read the Set-Cookie headers
            // unfortunately cookie jars do not handle redirects in a proper manner
            // and that's why I came to this question...
            fmt.Printf("%+v", resp.Cookies())
        }
    }
}
```

```
httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: RedirectChecker{}}
httpClient.Do(...)
```